# MATLAB : identifying the parameters corresponding to the loop variable

Tags: matlab, ode

I have trying to plot solutions to coupled ODEs.I solve them using ODE15s solver and pass arguments using a for loop.
MATLAB code then returns a set of plots to me(using hold on).Now only one of the given graphs is appropriate to my theory.So,how do I identify the argument(that I had passed through the for loop) which corresponds to my chosen graph(I can pick out the graph visually)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'text' function to mark the arguments nearby the each graph.There is  a very simple demo(a is the argument):

```
x=0:100;
figure;
hold on;
for a=1:10
    plot(x,a*x);
    text(100,a*100,sprintf('a=%s',num2str(a)));
end
```

Sorry for not pasting picture here because my reputation is not enough.